# Which misdeeds of F. Reineke was J.B.B. de Lesseps "obliged to suppress"?

Tags: russia, 18th-century, government, crime, kamchatka

F. Reineke was commandant of Kamchatka from about 1780 to 1784. According to Витер's *История символов как история административного деления государства* he was responsible for moving the territorial administration from Bolsheretesk to Nizhnekamchatsk. According to J.B.B. de Lesseps, Reineke resigned in 1784 ["for reasons which I am obliged to suppress"](https://archive.org/details/travelsinkamtsch01less/page/140).

It was common for Siberian administrators to be venal. According to Forsyth's *A history of the peoples of Siberia*, the very first governor of Siberia, Matvei Gagarin, was hanged for fraud, nepotism, and selling offices; another governor in Irkutsk was relieved from office for gross corruption and replaced with his second, who was "vicious" and "ruthless".

**Was Reineke guilty of the same old corruption and exploitation, or something worse?** I'm skeptical that de Lesseps, a Frenchman, had any reason to suppress a story of Russian corruption.

Comment: Consistently high quality questions. Thank you for your contributions to the site.

Comment: Thanks, Mark, for your help along the way!

Comment: Gagarin was not hanged (just) for corruption, Russian Wikipedia mentions that he attempted to form separate Siberian kingdom : https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%93%D0%B0%D0%B3%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BD,_%D0%9C%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%B5%D0%B9_%D0%9F%D0%B5%D1%82%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%87

Comment: For what it is worth, A. S. Sgibnev in his detailed "[History of main events in Kamchatka, 1650 - 1856](http://fishmuseum.ru/?d=history&con=mpub&linkid=280&id_cont=141&t_name=museum_pub&n=141&id=280&title=%C8%D1%D2%CE%D0%C8%D7%C5%D1%CA%C8%C9+%CE%D7%C5%D0%CA+%C3%CB%C0%C2%CD%C5%C9%D8%C8%D5+%D1%CE%C1%DB%D2%C8%C9+%3Cbr%3E%C2+%CA%C0%CC%D7%C0%D2%CA%C5.+1650%971855+%28%CE%EA%EE%ED%F7%E0%ED%E8%E5%29)", describes F. Reineke as "honest and entrepreneurial."

Comment: @MoisheKohan Very interesting. As Reineke was a public servant, I wonder if "entrepreneurial" was a backhanded compliment.

Comment: The original says "деятельный";  "Active" might be a better translation. You can also try to get the book ["Правители Камчатки : 1700-2007"](https://search.library.wisc.edu/catalog/9910079114302121) via an interlibrary loan and look there for further information.

Comment: One more thing: According to [this source](http://qwercus.narod.ru/reyneke_bio.htm), in 1786 F. Reineke moves from Kamchatka to Irkutsk and in 1798 retires from the civil service. All this suggests that his record in Kamchatka was just fine. There was some controversy related to his subordinates, as well as some misdeeds in the Russian postal service in Kamchatka during Reineke's tenure. Maybe this is what Lesseps alludes to.